# How to show flash message of before_action filter authenticate_user! on a action which is called through ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote], not`enter code here`ice: "you must logged in first!!!" 
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:name, :email, :password,
        :password_confirmation, :avatar)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:name, :email, :password,
        :password_confirmation, :current_password, :remove_avatar, :avatar)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the `post controller` in which vote method is called by ajax:

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:search]
      @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at ASC")
    else
      @posts = Post.all.order('created_at ASC')
    end
  end

  def show_all_post_of_current_user
    @current_user_posts = current_user.posts.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def vote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @vote = @post.votes.new :user_id => current_user.id, :vote => params[:vote]
    @vote.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        if @vote.valid?
          flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for voting.'
        else
          flash[:error] = 'You can only vote on a post once.'
        end
        redirect_to :back
      end
      format.js
    end
  end  

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def display_post_of_current_user
    @display = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to display_post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(edit_post_params)
      redirect_to display_post_path(@post)
      flash[:success] = "Post updated successfully"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to post_path
    flash[:success] = "Post deleted successfully"
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :date, :category, :picture)
  end

  def edit_post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<h1>Post Description</h1>
<p>
Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> 
      by <%= @post.user.email %>

</p>
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to vote_post_path(@post, vote: true), method: 'post', remote: true do %>
    <span> Up </span> | <span id='post_<%=@post.id%>_votes'><%= @post.up_votes %></span>
  <%end %>

  <%= link_to vote_post_path(@post, vote: false), method: 'post', remote: true do %>
    <span> Down </span> | <span id='post_<%=@post.id%>_votes'><%= @post.down_votes %></span>
  <%end %>

  <span id='post_<%=@post.id%>_votes'><%= @post.total_votes %> votes</span> |
  <%= link_to "Back", posts_path %> 
</p>
```

**vote.js.erb**

```
<% if @vote.valid? %>
  $("#post_<%= @post.id %>_votes").html("<%= @post.total_votes %> votes")
  $("#post_<%= @post.id %>up_votes").html("<%= @post.up_votes %>")
  $("#post_<%= @post.id %>down_votes").html("<%= @post.down_votes %>")
<% else %>
  alert('You can only vote on a post once.');
<% end %>
```

While user click on upvote or downvote link an ajax is called on vote method of post controller. and a filter on application controller restrict user to perform voting until user logged_in I use before filter for authenticate user method of devise.
But don't know how to generate flash while user click on upvote or downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call flash message inside your js.erb file which you are calling when the user clicks on the vote.

**vote.js.erb**

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

You might have to change your respond_to block

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @vote.valid?
    format.html { flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for voting.' }
    format.js   { flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for voting.' }
  else
    format.html { flash[:error] = 'You can only vote on a post once.'}
    format.js   { flash[:error] = 'You can only vote on a post once.'}
  end
end
```

it might also help you [form_with_ajax](http://ericlondon.com/2014/03/13/rails-4-submit-modal-form-via-ajax-and-render-js-response-as-table-row.html)

**Update**
You need do your own authenticate_user! action and in this action, you can have the behaviour your want. put message what you want on js file

```
def authenticate_user!
  unless current_user
    render 'yourjs'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i wanted to show flash message of authenticate_user! method of devise if user not logged in it not allowed user to vote and show flash message as  "you need to login first" or whatever the flash message of devise authenticate_user! method does and redirect to login page as i call authenticate_user! filter on vote method.

Comment: def authenticate_user!
  unless current_user
    render 'yourjs'
  end
end "This works for me Thanks!!!"

Comment: @Divya Could you please share how did you implement                                  "def authenticate_user! unless current_user render 'yourjs' end end "